# async and await, expecting non-blocking in main

Tags: c#, asynchronous

From my understanding of the `async` keyword the usage of `await` in combination is used to create a continuation point for when the result of an asynchronous operation is actually needed, allowing other work to be done in the interim.

Then why is the following blocking? I would expect `Nothing to do while the awaits complete, expecting this line to come first.` to be the first line of output to the console..

In `tasks.cs`

```
public static async Task Execute()
{
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    await Foo();
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"Execute completed in {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms.");
}

private static async Task Foo()
{
    var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 5).Select(x =>
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew((b) =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            int value = (int) b;
            Console.WriteLine($"Task ran on thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
            return value * value;
        }, x);
    }).ToArray();

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Which is called in main

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    await Tasks.Execute();
    var result = await LongRunningOperation();
    Console.WriteLine("Nothing to do while the awaits complete, expecting this line to come first.");
    Console.WriteLine($"Long running operation result: {result}");
}

private static async Task<int> LongRunningOperation()
{
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    var res = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        Console.WriteLine($"Long running operation completed on thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
        return 10000;
    });
    sw.Stop();

    return res;
}
```

Which outputs the following:

```
Task ran on thread: 7
Task ran on thread: 4
Task ran on thread: 3
Task ran on thread: 5
Task ran on thread: 6
Execute completed in 113ms.
Long running operation completed on thread 9
Nothing to do while the awaits complete, expecting this line to come first.
Long running operation result: 10000
```

Which means that I am blocking in this context and everything is chained together sequentially... what am I not understanding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/await):

> The await operator is applied to a task in an asynchronous method to insert a suspension point in the execution of the method until the awaited task completes

By writing `var result = await LongRunningOperation();` you suspend any further action until `LongRunningOperation` has completed.

If you rewrite your `Main` to look like this:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var longTask = LongRunningOperation();
    Console.WriteLine("Nothing to do while the awaits complete, expecting this line to come first.");
    var result = await longTask;
    Console.WriteLine($"Long running operation result: {result}");
}
```

then your program will print the expected line, and **then** wait for task completion before it tries to output the result.

Comment: Oh I see, I have misunderstood entirely then, thanks for clearing this up. Essentially I get a token of work in the form of the async Task and I can block for its result when I want with await.

Comment: @arynaq Correct, the important word there is *when*, you can grab the task, continue executing other code, and then await the task when you cannot continue without the result of that task.